# A problem happens when using XeTeX compiling with IEEE Trans class

Tags: xetex, pdftex, ieeetran

I encountered a problem when XeTeX is utilized to compile a document in IEEE Trans class.

With the IEEE trans class, the default Time New Roman font is automatically replaced by Computer Modern font when XeTeX is applied as the engine. In contrast, if I just use the LateX engine, then the default font can be displayed correctly.

I have tried to compile a document with the most simple syntax in the preamble, but the above problem still occurred.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: If this is for submission can the IEEE use xetex at all for publications?  If not for submission it's probably better to use a more flexible class

Comment: You need to load times with fontspec and `\setmainfont`. But IEEEtran is doing a lot fine tuning and settings based on the assumption that pdflatex is used so (as David wrote) it is probably not really a good idea to use it with xelatex.

Comment: OK, thank you for the suggestion. The reason I may need to use XeTeX is due to the number of the math font limitation in LateX.

Comment: @Johannes but are you planning to submit to an IEEE journal, if so you can not change the fonts, the journal choose such details.